# POSIX path in applescript from list not opening. Raw path works

Tags: string, macos, applescript, posix

I'm really confused with this one. All I want is the files in the list to open. Here's my codes

```
set FilesList to {"Users/XXXXXX/Documents/07PictureArt-Related/THINGS THAT HELP/Tutorials/artNotesfromFeng.rtf", "Users/XXXXXXXX/Documents/07PictureArt-Related/THINGS THAT HELP"}

repeat with theFiles in FilesList
    delay 0.1
    tell application "Finder" to open POSIX file (theFiles)
end repeat
```

So, how come THAT won't work, but this will???

```
tell application "Finder" to open POSIX file "Users/XXXXXX/Documents/07PictureArt-Related/THINGS THAT HELP/Tutorials/artNotesfromFeng.rtf"
```

I'm thinking it might have to do with maybe the list is making it a string, and when I plug it directly into the open command, it LOOKS like a string, but it's not really...I don't know

For now I guess I just have to brute force it, and make a new statement for each file.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what is going on there, i agree it's confusing.

An alternate is to use the shell 'open' command instead.

```
repeat with filePath in FilesList
    do shell script "open " & quoted form of filePath
end repeat
```

The shell seems more happy with POSIX paths, the trick is to send in the 'quoted form' of your POSIX paths.

--
EDIT:
Putting into a var first works too.

```
repeat with theFiles in FilesList
    set f to POSIX file theFiles
    tell application "Finder" to open f
end repeat
```

It seems the Finder is causing the coercion to POSIX file problem.

Answer (score 0):

Either of these works:

```
set l to {"/bin", "/etc"}
repeat with f in l
    tell application "Finder" to open (POSIX file (contents of f) as alias)
end repeat
```

```
set l to {"/bin", "/etc"}
repeat with f in l
    POSIX file f
    tell application "Finder" to open result
end repeat
```

Try running this script:

```
set l to {"/bin", "/etc"}
repeat with f in l
    f
end repeat
```

The result at the end is `item 2 of {"/bin", "/etc"}`. `contents of` returns the target of the reference object.

I don't know why `POSIX file f` doesn't work inside a `tell application "Finder"` block, or why `POSIX file f as alias` does work.