# How to turn an AppleScript path into a posix path and pass to shell script?

Tags: shell, ffmpeg, applescript

I´m trying to create a textfile that my ffmpeg-command can use to merge two videofiles. The problem I´m having is getting my folder/file-paths to look like I want. The two lines that cause my problems are:

`set theFile to path to replay_folder & "ls.txt"`

I simply want this path to be the path of `replay_folder` and `ls.txt`

In the shell script line I want the same thing.

`do shell script "cd " & replay_folder & "
    /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -f concat -i ls.txt -c copy merged.mov"`

I get this path with the shell script `Macintosh HD:Users:BjornFroberg:Documents:wirecast:Replay-2017-03-17-12_11-1489749062:`

But I want this `/Users/BjornFroberg/Documents/wirecast/Replay-2017-03-17-12_11-1489749062/`

The full code is:

```
tell application "Finder"
set sorted_list to sort folders of folder ("Macintosh HD:Users:bjornfroberg:documents:wirecast:") by creation date
set replay_folder to item -1 of sorted_list
set replay_files to sort items of replay_folder by creation date
end tell

set nr4 to "file '" & name of item -4 of replay_files & "'"
set nr3 to "file '" & name of item -3 of replay_files & "'"

set theText to nr4 & return & nr3

set overwriteExistingContent to true

set theFile to path to replay_folder & "ls.txt" --actual path is: POSIX file "/Users/BjornFroberg/Documents/wirecast/Replay-2017-03-17-12_11-1489749062/ls.txt"

set theOpenedFile to open for access file theFile with write permission

if overwriteExistingContent is true then set eof of theOpenedFile to 0

write theText to theOpenedFile starting at eof

close access theOpenedFile

do shell script "cd " & replay_folder & "
/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -f concat -i ls.txt -c copy merged.mov"
```

Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`path to` is part of Standard Scripting Additions and works only with predefined folders. It does not work with custom paths. For example `"Macintosh HD:Users:bjornfroberg:documents:"` can be replaced with the relative path

```
set documentsFolder to path to documents folder as text
```

which points always to the documents folder of the current user.

---

`replay_folder` is a Finder object specifier which can - in this particular form – only be handled be the Finder. To create an (colon separated) **HFS path** you need to coerce the Finder specifier to text

```
set theFile to (replay_folder as text) & "ls.txt"
```

However to pass the `replay_folder` to the shell you have to use a **POSIX path** (slash separated). Since a Finder specifier cannot be coerced directly to `POSIX path` you need also first create a `HFS path`. Additionally you have to take care that space characters are escaped in the path. Any unescaped space character will break the shell script

```
set replay_folderPOSIX to POSIX path of (replay_folder as text)
do shell script "cd " & quoted form of replay_folderPOSIX & "
/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -f concat -i ls.txt -c copy merged.mov"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can convert an AppleScript path to a Posix path like this:

```
set applescriptPath to "Macintosh HD:Users:bjornfroberg:documents:wirecast:"

set posixPath to (the POSIX path of applescriptPath)

log posixPath
```

Returns `/Users/bjornfroberg/documents/wirecast/`

Note: Your post's title and your actual question are kind of different topics. Your goal is to turn an AppleScript path (`Macintosh HD:Users:bjornfroberg:documents:wirecast`) into a posix path (`/Users/bjornfroberg/documents/wirecast/`), to which you want to append a file name; you can use the code above in conjunction with your existing code to build the full path:

```
set theFile to POSIX path of (replay_folder as text) & "ls.txt"
```

Depending what you're trying to do, once you have defined your path, you may need to convert it to a posix **file** to manipulate it via AppleScript. For example, if you want to open it via AppleScript:

```
set pFile to POSIX file theFile

tell application "Finder" to open pFile
```

(See [POSIX path in applescript from list not opening. Raw path works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18525132/posix-path-in-applescript-from-list-not-opening-raw-path-works))